# WPF - Draw multiple Rectangles on Canvas in parallel

Tags: c#, wpf, parallel-processing, drawing

I have class BBox, which repesents Rectangle - it contains cooridinates(x, y, width, height) and color of rectangle. Then I have List of these BBoxes, which contains circa 4000  of them. I need to draw all boxes which are stored in a List on a Canvas as fast as possible. What is the most effective way?

```
    private List<BBox> FoundBoxes { get; set; }

    public void DrawBoxes(Canvas canvas)
    {
            foreach (var box in FoundBoxes)
            {
                var brush = box.getColor();
                System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle rect;
                rect = new System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle
                {
                    Stroke = brush,
                    Height = box.Height,
                    Width = box.Width,
                    StrokeThickness = 1
                };
                Canvas.SetLeft(rect, box.TopLeftX);
                Canvas.SetTop(rect, box.TopLeftY);
                canvas.Children.Add(rect);
            }
```

}

Code above takes more than 1 second, which is slow for my application. I am sure that there must be a way to do it in parallel. So I tried this:

```
 Parallel.ForEach(FoundBoxes, box =>
 {
      ...same method body...
 });
```

but it throws

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this.'
```

I am aware why this exceprtion occurs, and I tried to find solution, but nothing works for me. For example I tried running it using **Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>** or running it using new **Thread** as stated here:

```
Thread t = new Thread(delegate ()
{
    Parallel.ForEach(FoundBoxes, box =>
    {
      ...same method body...
    });
});
t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
t.IsBackground = true;
t.Start();
```

but it still throws mentioned exception. How can I solve this? Or is there any better / more effective way to draw multiple objects on canvas? Thank you.

Comment: As far as I understand how the wpf works the access to the UI context is sequential so, parallelazing wont give much effort. Probably you have to for directly with DrawingVisuals and take care about other UI stuff by yourself (I mean, mous handling, hovering otc.. ).  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/using-drawingvisual-objects

wpf is not designed for the super fast visualization. ( you can do of course) but you have to work higher than  FrameworkElement.

Investigate the WPF FrameworkElement structure. Would be much easier to understand what to do

Comment: How many different colors do the rectangles have? Maybe you can use a single Path for each color where each uses a GeometryGroup as its Data, with a lot of RectangleGeometries.

Comment: You may also create GeometryDrawings for each Rectangle and add them to a DrawingGroup which you display in a DrawingBrush.Takes 200-300 ms for me for 4000 rectangles.

Comment: Another alternative: WriteableBitmapEx.

Comment: Allright, thank you for your advices, GeometryDrawing and WriteableBitmap both look useful, I am sure that they will do the job. You really helped me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allright I solved my problem using [WriteableBitmapEx](https://github.com/reneschulte/WriteableBitmapEx) as Clemens recommended. Now, 4000+ boxes are drawn in real-time.